# libGDX html:draftCompileGwt Compilation Error

Tags: java, html, gwt, libgdx

I've created a libGDX desktop and html project and I'm trying to run the html version. Currently the desktop version runs perfectly however I keep on getting the following error when running the HTML application:

**Stack Trace**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':html:draftCompileGwt'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':html:draftCompileGwt'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:389)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.javaexec(DefaultFileOperations.java:183)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1077)
        at org.wisepersist.gradle.plugins.gwt.AbstractGwtActionTask.exec(AbstractGwtActionTask.java:79)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:788)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:755)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        ... 30 more
```

and the debug log when failure occurs:

```
20:03:34.977 [QUIET] [system.out] Loading inherited module 'xx.GdxDefinitionSuperdev'
20:03:35.003 [QUIET] [system.out]    Module location: file:/C:/Users/xx/GdxDefinitionSuperdev.gwt.xml
20:03:35.203 [QUIET] [system.out] Checking for updates
20:03:35.204 [QUIET] [system.out]    Failed to obtain current version info via HTTP
20:03:35.918 [QUIET] [system.out]    Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'
```

So I attempted to import *Core* and *User* as recommended like so in my GDXDefinitionSuperdev class like so but the errors still remain:

**GDXDefinitionSuperdev**

```
<module rename-to="html">
    <inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gdx_backends_gwt' />
    <inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.box2d-gwt' />
    <inherits name='Box2DLights' />
    <inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.ai' />
    <inherits name='com.badlogic.ashley_gwt' />

    <inherits name='uk.ac.aston.team17.GdxDefinition' />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.Core" />

    <collapse-all-properties />

    <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>   
    <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
    <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/> 
</module>
```

Any help to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: If it helps in any way, the 'http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd' link in the DOCTYPE declaration is not registering in the IDE. If this may be the issue, how can I get around this?

Comment: Hi, How did you run the process?
Did you run `./gradlew html:superDev` ?

Comment: Hi, yes I ran it with ./gradlew.bat html:superDev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my GWT config file. That runs. Hope it helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
  <module rename-to="html">
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP"/>
  <inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gdx_backends_gwt' />
  <inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.box2d-gwt' />
  <inherits name='com.project.GdxDefinition' />
  <inherits name='MyProjectPackage1' />
  <inherits name='MyProjectPackage2' />

  <collapse-all-properties />
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/> 
  <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
  <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>
  <set-configuration-property name="gdx.assetpath" value="../project/assets" />
  <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>
</module>
```

For each class package which I inherit above (MyProjectPackage1 and 2) I have a xml file MyProjectPackage1.xml in my source folder pointing to the the class package

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
 <module>
    <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
    <source path="com/Project/classpackage" />
 </module>
```